# Preprocessor pasting of UTF-8 characters does 'not give a valid preprocessing token' in g++

Tags: c++, gcc, utf-8, g++

Given the below application, g++ can't seem to concatenate 2 UTF-8 characters, but it's fine handling ascii range stuff. Is this expected behavior? How can I make this work? I'm running this in in a linux environment, and the source file is saved as UTF-8 (tried with and without BOM, to no avail). Note I need this to create the token before the C++ compiler is called, so relying on ("foo" "bar") becoming ("foobar") won't work in my case, much to my annoyance.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define Q(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x, y) Q(x ## y)

#define RU2(root) cout << QUOTE(root,る) << #root << QUOTE(root,れ) << QUOTE(root,ろ) << QUOTE(root,よ) << endl;

int main()
{
    RU2(着);
    return 0;
}
```

> sandbox.cpp:13:1: error: pasting "▒" and "▒" does not give a valid
>   preprocessing token sandbox.cpp:13:1: error: pasting "▒" and "▒" does
>   not give a valid preprocessing token sandbox.cpp:13:1: error: pasting
>   "▒" and "▒" does not give a valid preprocessing token
>   sandbox.cpp:13:1: error: pasting "▒" and "▒" does not give a valid
>   preprocessing token

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Token concatenation -- the `##` preprocess operator -- must produce a *valid token*, and it is intended to do just that. You can use it to generate an identifier from different pieces. For example, you could generate unique labels by concatenating some prefix (`label`) with the preprocessor macro `__LINE__`.

But you cannot use token concatenation to produce a non-token, and you cannot always use it to produce a valid token. For example, you cannot use `##` to paste together `.` and `.`, because `..` is not a valid token, and that means that there is no way to generate the token `...` because it cannot be decomposed into two valid tokens. [Note 1]. Similarly, it is impossible to create a string literal (which is a token) by token pasting two pieces, because no token can contain a single <kbd>"</kbd> (or <kbd>'</kbd>). [Note 2] [Note 3].

An identifier token consists of an "identifier-nondigit" followed by any number of "digit" or "identifier-nondigit" characters. An "identifier-nondigit" can be <kbd>_</kbd>, an Ascii letter, a "universal character name" (that is, `\u` followed by four hex digits or `\U` followed by eight hex digits) or "other implementation-defined characters". Universal character names must always be valid Unicode codepoints, and the ones used in identifiers must fall into a restricted subset of Unicode, specified in Appendix D of the C standard (which is normative).

In the case of GCC, the only "other implementation-defined character" is <kbd>$</kbd>, and then only if an appropriate command-line flag is specified. So the only way to use a non-Ascii Unicode character is with a universal character name. Clang, on the other hand, does not have this restriction; Unicode characters which are in the subset defined in Appendix D may be used directly in identifiers.

As it happens, the characters in the OP all fall into this restricted subset. So switching to the Clang preprocessor would work, in this particular example.

However, there is really no need to rely on non-portable extensions in order to create string literals with extended characters. In general, the contents of a string literal is not required to be a valid token and you cannot manufacture an arbitrary string literal by stringifying the result of a token concatenation. But that doesn't matter, for two reasons:

1. C will merge two (or more) consecutive string literals into a single string literal. So, for example, `"着" "る"` is exactly the same as `"着る"`. Consequently, you can separately stringify the various parts of the desired string, using a macro something like:

   ```
   #define QUOTE(x, y) Q(x) Q(y)
   ```

   In the vast majority of cases, this will be the correct solution.
2. Even if the above is not possible -- a classic case is the quoted filename specification in an `#include` statement -- you can still use the stringify operator (`#`) because that operator does not only work on single tokens. The argument to the stringify operator is a macro *argument*, which is a stream of tokens and whitespace. When doing this, it is sometimes useful to use the "identity" macro `#define I(X) X` in order to avoid introducing undesired whitespace. For example:

   ```
   // Extra level of indirection in order to forced substitution
   // of the argument to Q
   #define Q_(X) #X
   #define Q(X) Q_(X)
   // Identity macro
   #define I(X) X

   // Stringify two arguments without intervening whitespace
   #define QUOTE2(X,Y) Q(I(X)I(Y))
   const char* s = QUOTE2(着,る);
   ```

---

#### Notes

1. Some non-standards compliant preprocessors (some versions of MSVC, for example) may allow pasting together three dots using two `##` operators. But that is not portable.
2. Backslash escapes like `\"` aren't tokens, either; the backslash escape sequence is only meaningful *within string literals*. In program text, a `\` is a single-character token, except for backslashes appearing as part of a line continuation sequence, which are not tokens at all.
3. You can, however, use token concatenation to paste an encoding prefix such as `L` onto an unprefixed string literal.

Comment: The goal in this case is to do this entirely inside the pre-processor. As it turns out, it needs to be combined before the compiler is called. Based on this and the other answer, I think the result is simply "you can't do that".

Comment: @Rollie: Answer edited to include both the suggestion to use the Clang preprocessor, and an alternative mechanism which does work with both GCC and Clang (and which should work with any compliant preprocessor, provided that Unicode characters are permitted in source code).

Comment: ... In future, please recall that the purpose of SO is to be a repository of good questions and useful answers which are of general applicability. It is your responsibility to ask the question whose answer you require; if you later discover that you have asked a question whose answer does not apply to your particular use case, please ask a new, more specific question, rather than editing your original question in  a way which invalidates answers already contributed.

Answer (score 1):

I think GCC does not directly support this at present.  The manual says this about [input character sets](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Character-sets.html):

> In identifiers, characters outside the ASCII range can only be specified with the ‘`\u`’ and ‘`\U`’ escapes, not used directly.

Following this advice, I changed your program to:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

#define Q(x) #x
#define QUOTE(x, y) Q(x ## y)

#define RU2(root) \
  cout << QUOTE(root,\u308b) << #root << QUOTE(root,\u308c) \
  << QUOTE(root,\u308d) << QUOTE(root,\u3088) << endl;

int main()
{ 
  RU2(\u7740);
  return 0;
}
```

And it seems to work as intended.

Comment: Depends on the CPP. The latest version is supposed to work over Unicode.

Comment: Well if that's not the ugliest code I've ever seen...though it seems like this is the answer, as much as I'd rather it wasn't.